# wp search-replace returns no output on Multisite installation

Tags: multisite, database, urls, wp-cli, command-line

I'm running multisite. Looking to replace old URLs with new URLs for pulling a copy of the site form one environment to another environment.

**Here is my command:**

```
wp search-replace --url=domain.com https://domain.com https://domain.test --all-tables --network --recurse-objects --skip-columns=guid --dry-run --allow-root --debug
```

WP-CLI is just taking my command and going to a new line, then returns nothing.

**When I add `--debug` this is what I get back:**

```
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.093s)
Debug (bootstrap): Using project config: //wp-cli.yml (0.094s)
Debug (bootstrap): argv: /usr/local/bin/wp search-replace --url=domain.com https://domain.com https://domain.test --all-tables --network --recurse-objects --skip-columns=guid --dry-run --allow-root --debug (0.094s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /app/public/ (0.096s)
Debug (bootstrap): Set URL: domain.com (0.097s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.102s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /app/public/wp-config.php (0.103s)
```

I run this very same command on another installation and it runs just fine. What could cause this to fail? Differences in `wp-config.php` by chance? Is there anything required in `wp-config.php` to run properly?

Comment: I wonder why it's stopping at wp-config path. What is `wp cli version` and `wp core version` returning you? And `wp core is-installed && echo $?` should return you a 0 if installed. I only had this yesterday, locally, but couldn't reproduce it anymore after I imported a fresh live database dump again.

Comment: Have a look at your PHP errors. I've seen WP CLI fail like that because PHP fatals out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was definitely a discrepancy with loading site related assets.

I was also executing several unnecessary parameters with my command.

I was unaware you could prevent these assets from loading during this operation. Please see the new command on how to prevent loading possible conflicting files.

**I've modified it to the following and it worked as expected:**

```
wp search-replace --url=domain.com domain.com domain.test --allow-root --all-tables --skip-themes --skip-plugins --skip-packages --verbose
```

Comment: --skip-plugins is what did it for me. If there's a not installed plugin present in `active_plugins` wp search-replace also fails. Or you could just empty the `active_plugins` row in `wp_options`.

Comment: `wp search-replace domain.old domain.new --all-tables` worked for my problematic Multisite installation, I didn't need any of the `skip` flags.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your PHP errors. I've seen WP CLI fail like that because PHP fatals out.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - I guess this is better as a comment instead?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.